# Magento 2 : System Configuration in main website not showing

Tags: magento2

In store different it showing but when i change to main website it not showing

Comment: Did you check the `showInDefault` and `showInWebsite` values? It should be `1`.

Comment: Yes, i have set it to 1 but it still empty

Comment: Please, show your code .

Comment: It too long. So i certain set whole to 1

Comment: After changing the values? Did you clear cache?

Comment: Yes, i did clear cache

Comment: add your system.xml file here

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below `system.xml` file working example for reference. And compare with your file. So you have helpful to fix the issue.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="testtab" translate="label" sortOrder="100" class="test-extensions">
             <label>Title</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="customsection" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="5" translate="label">
            <label>Title</label>
            <tab>testtab</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::vendor_module</resource>
            <group id="testgroup" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="0" translate="label">
                <attribute type="expanded">1</attribute>
                <label>Title</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```